# Sinatra Locals vs. Instance Variables

Tags: ruby, sinatra

What exactly are Sinatra’s locals, and is there any difference between using them in templates as opposed to instance variables? Here’s what I mean by [locals](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Views%20/%20Templates):

```
erb :template, :locals => {:variable => 'value'}
```

**Edit:**

In terms of implementation, what are the differences between instance and local variables, and are there any benefits to using one over the other?

Answer (score 5):

From Sinatra's [intro](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html):

*Templates are evaluated within the same context as route handlers. Instance variables set in route handlers are directly accessible by templates:*

```
get '/:id' do
  @foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
  haml '%h1= @foo.name'
end
```

Or, specify an explicit Hash of local variables:

```
get '/:id' do
  foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
  haml '%h1= bar.name', :locals => { :bar => foo }
end
```

This is typically used when rendering templates as partials from within other templates.

And for some templates there is (for Radius in this case):

*Since you cannot call Ruby methods directly from a Radius template, you almost always want to pass locals to it.*